# Explicit specialization in non-namespace scope

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

```
template<typename T>
class CConstraint
{
public:
    CConstraint()
    {
    }

    virtual ~CConstraint()
    {
    }
    
    template <typename TL>
    void Verify(int position, int constraints[])
    {       
    }

    template <>
    void Verify<int>(int, int[])
    {   
    }
};
```

Compiling this under g++ gives the following error:

> Explicit specialization in non-namespace scope 'class CConstraint'

In VC, it compiles fine. Can anyone please let me know the workaround?

Comment: Note that this is no longer a problem in C++17.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49707184/explicit-specialization-in-non-namespace-scope-does-not-compile-in-gcc

Answer (score 113, accepted):

VC++ is non-compliant in this case - explicit specializations have to be at namespace scope. C++03, *§14.7.3/2*:

> An explicit specialization shall be declared in the namespace of which the template is a member, or, for member templates, in the namespace of which the enclosing class or enclosing class template is a member.
>   An explicit specialization of a member function, member class or static data member of a class template shall be declared in the namespace of which the class template is a member.

Additionally you have the problem that you can't specialize member functions without explicitly specializing the containing class due to C++03, *§14.7.3/3*, so one solution would be to let `Verify()` forward to a, possibly specialized, free function:

```
namespace detail {
    template <typename TL> void Verify     (int, int[]) {}
    template <>            void Verify<int>(int, int[]) {}
}

template<typename T> class CConstraint {
    // ...
    template <typename TL> void Verify(int position, int constraints[]) {
        detail::Verify<TL>(position, constraints);
    }
};
```

Comment: *incompliant in this case*: as always :) ? Templates and VC++ don't mix that well :/

Comment: It's non-compliant in a sense that it will let you do something that the Standard normally doesn't allow - which isn't a problem for code that is conformant to begin with (you write such code, right? ~). The real conformance problems are when it won't compile something that the Standard requires to compile, or will behave differently from what is specified.

Comment: Like the subtle pitfalls arising from the missing two-phase lookup ... :|

Comment: Georg, Thanks for you answer....You actually delegate type deduction to Detail::Verify, so it is not a real CConstraint::Verify, but it works.)

Comment: Why would the language developers do this to programmer developers?  Were they thinking, `How can we make this language any more difficult to read and write?`

Comment: i'm also wondering about thi, is there any particular reason on why the standard forbid this?

Comment: MSVC is "non-compliant" in failing to issue a diagnostic message. In all other respects there's nothing non-compliant in supporting this as an *extension*, unless you can show that it breaks compliant code. Extensions are not non-compliance issues.

Comment: This answer is not correct anymore, specialization is now allowed in class scope in conformant C++14 (& later) compilers : https://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue727

Comment: @Adrian imho in some cases this ruling increases readability... having a dozen of specializations swarming inside of class is a chore to parse. For human

Comment: Since this is currently the top google result, I'd suggest we edit this answer to include what Jean-Michaël Celerier said. Or maybe link to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49707184/explicit-specialization-in-non-namespace-scope-does-not-compile-in-gcc), which is more up to date. In the end, I disagree with what Swift said and I think that this ruling only hurts readability. Well, he did say "in some cases" though. Anyway, I think now it is more a matter of GCC devs being stubborn than anything else. Both MSVC and CLANG can handle those specializations.

Answer (score 105):

Another way to solve it is by delegating to a private function and overloading that function. This way you still have access to member data of `*this` and to the outer template parameter type.

```
template<typename T>
struct identity { typedef T type; };

template<typename T>
class CConstraint
{
public:

  template <typename TL>
  void Verify(int position, int constraints[])
  {
    Verify(position, constraints, identity<TL>());
  }

private:
  template<typename TL>
  void Verify(int, int[], identity<TL>)
  {

  }

  void Verify(int, int[], identity<int>)
  {

  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was looking for this also as I need to access this. Wish I could select 2 answers.

Comment: If I were you, I'd choose this answer.
@Johannes: Your answer is just perfect, thanks.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you, Johannes Schaub, for this answer.

Comment: This answer is a lot more useful than the accepted one.

Comment: Any changes since C++11 came around?

Comment: because `templated Verify` functions are private, `struct identity` can be put inside the class as private type.

Comment: I tried this solution and it didn't work for me until I realized that the public function "Verify" must be called with a type.  Like: `Verify<int>(..)` or `Verify<double>(...)`.  The compiler cannot deduce it automatically.

Answer (score 23):

Just take the template specialization outside the class declaration.
gcc doesn't allow inline template specialization.

As another option, just deleting line
template<>
seems to work for me.

Comment: 1st sentence is on the money: "gcc doesn't allow inline template specialization".

Comment: Removing the `template<>` worked for me as well.

Answer (score 5):

Even better: you can combine partial specialisation with default template arguments. This way modification to the VC++ code are minor, because calls to the specialised function do not need to be modified.

```
template <typename TL, class Dummy=int>
void Verify(int position, int constraints[])
{
}

template <class Dummy=int>
void Verify<int, Dummy>(int, int[])
{
}
```

Comment: Default template arguments aren't allowed in C++03, only in C++0x/11.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong: you cannot partially specialise a function.

Comment: @Xeo: I guess you meant not allowed on functions in C++03?  "A default template-argument is a template-argument (14.3) specified after `=` in a template-parameter. A
default template-argument may be specified for any kind of template-parameter (type, non-type, template).
A default template-argument may be specified in a class template declaration or a class template definition.
**A default template-argument shall not be specified in a function template declaration or a function template
definition, nor in the template-parameter-list of the definition of a member of a class template.**"

Answer (score 2):

You may not be able to **explicitly specialize** the member template, but you can *partially* specialize it.  If you add a second parameter "int dummyParam" and also add it to the specialization, it should work with both compilers.

Not that I knew this more than 10 seconds ago, but googling on the same error, I ran into [this link](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/explicit-specialization-in-non-namespace-scope-186352/) and it worked for my member template specialization.

Comment: You cannot partially specialize a function