# type-safe compile-time fixed-size container in Scala?

Tags: scala, generics, types, generic-programming

I want to design a type safe fix-sized container in Scala - that is a container, size of which is designated in its type signature. I want the possible size to be able to reach arbitrarily large values - 1000 would be something normal.

This is the only approach I figured out so far:

```
package net.almost_done.trees
case class FixSizedContainer[T, S <: Sizable](val values: Vector[T], s: S) {
  assert(values.length == s.getSize)

  def mate(other: FixSizedContainer[T, S]): FixSizedContainer[T, S] = {
    ??? //some code that makes sense here
  }
}

object FixSizedContainer {
  def size(i: Int): Sizable = ???
}

trait Sizable {
  def getSize: Int
}

case class ZeroSize(sth:Any) extends Sizable { //this should be an object but then I have an "not found: type ZeroSize" error
  val getSize = 0
}

case class SizeDesignator[S <: Sizable](oneLess: S) extends Sizable {
  def getSize: Int = oneLess.getSize + 1
}
```

And the desired use case would look as follows:

```
val fs1000 = FixSizedContainer(someVec, FixSizedContainer.size(1000))
```

My approach is working (kind of) - the container size id enforced:

```
scala> import net.almost_done.trees._
import net.almost_done.trees._

scala> val fix_one = FixSizedContainer[String, SizeDesignator[ZeroSize]](Vector("foo"), SizeDesignator(ZeroSize(0)))
fix_one: net.almost_done.trees.FixSizedContainer[String,net.almost_done.trees.SizeDesignator[net.almost_done.trees.ZeroSize]] = FixSizedContainer(Vector(foo),SizeDesignator(ZeroSize(0)))

scala> val fix_one_prime = FixSizedContainer[String, SizeDesignator[ZeroSize]](Vector("bar"), SizeDesignator(ZeroSize(0)))
fix_one_prime: net.almost_done.trees.FixSizedContainer[String,net.almost_done.trees.SizeDesignator[net.almost_done.trees.ZeroSize]] = FixSizedContainer(Vector(bar),SizeDesignator(ZeroSize(0)))

scala> val fix_zero = FixSizedContainer[String, ZeroSize](Vector(), ZeroSize)
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : net.almost_done.trees.ZeroSize.type
 required: net.almost_done.trees.ZeroSize
       val fix_zero = FixSizedContainer[String, ZeroSize](Vector(), ZeroSize)
                                                                    ^

scala> val fix_zero = FixSizedContainer[String, ZeroSize](Vector(), ZeroSize(0))
fix_zero: net.almost_done.trees.FixSizedContainer[String,net.almost_done.trees.ZeroSize] = FixSizedContainer(Vector(),ZeroSize(0))

scala> fix_one
fix_one         fix_one_prime   

scala> fix_one.mate(fix_one_prime)
scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing (this was expecte)


scala> fix_one.mate(fix_zero)
<console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : net.almost_done.trees.FixSizedContainer[String,net.almost_done.trees.ZeroSize]
 required: net.almost_done.trees.FixSizedContainer[String,net.almost_done.trees.SizeDesignator[net.almost_done.trees.ZeroSize]]
              fix_one.mate(fix_zero)
```

There are two problems however:

1. When I get to bigger sizes like the 1000 I was talking about earlier, the types will be enormously bloated. A perfect solution would have small SizeDesignator classes.
2. I can't get any reasonable shorthand for getting the `SizeDesignator` for a size I wanted. The `FixSizedContainer.size(x)` would have to have a specific type, which is the opposite what I want.

As a sidenote: I'm pretty sure the typesafe FixSizedContainer would even be possible in C++, using [template specialization with constant values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840819/c-template-specialization-with-constant-value).

Any idea how to achieve the results I want better?

And no, `TupleN` is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: A similar functionality is implemented in Shapeless (https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#collections-with-statically-know-sizes) probably you can ask them about their experiences.

Comment: good catch! I'm looking at their code now.

Comment: And [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21296099/limits-of-nat-type-in-shapeless) is a very related question (it's also worth looking at the comments)