# Custom RTTI information using templates

Tags: c++, templates, rtti

I have wrapper classes for SpiderMonkey API where I need to define methods with a specific signature. I have a solution based on templates. Basically, I have several template methods to handle hundreds of wrapper methods, like this (simplified):

```
template <typename jsType, AIErr(*Type::*Method)()>
    static bool ExecuteMethod(JSContext *cx, unsigned argc, JS::Value *vp)
{
...
}
```

I use it as follows, using macros:

```
#define EXECUTE_METHOD_AIERR_X(TYPE, METHOD) \
JS_FN(#METHOD, (js##TYPE::ExecuteMethod<js##TYPE, &TYPE::METHOD>), 0, 0)
```

If I have a situation when I need to debug, in order to know which method (*Method) of which class (*Type) was handled at a specific time, **I would need to know the name of the type *Type* and the name of the method *Method* inside that template method**. Due to the nature of SpiderMonkey's API, I can't alter the parameters of ExecuteMethod, just the template.

I've seen these:

[C++ Get name of type in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055452/c-get-name-of-type-in-template)

[C++ Template Specialization with Constant Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840819/c-template-specialization-with-constant-value)

I've tried these, but the solution just fails for me at the `typeid(T).name()` step on MSVC C++ 2013 compiler. On the other hand, how to apply this on methods?

Additionally, I see this:

```
template<typename T>
class TypeParseTraits{
public:
    static const std::string name(){
        return typeid(T).name();
    }
};

#define REGISTER_PARSE_TYPE(X) \
    template<> class TypeParseTraits< X > \
    { public: static const std::string name(){ return #X; } };
```

What is this `template<> class TypeParseTraits< X >`? An override? A specialization?

If I would do it by templates again, it would be necessary to be dependent on jsType, Type and Method.

My question is, how should I implement (even for debug only) a RTTI info using strings? What are the most effective options, if any?

I know that simple char* is not an option as parameter for templates.

Thank you.

Comment: _"What is this `template<> class ...`?"_ It's a template specialization.

Comment: why and how does `typeid` fail?

Comment: It's not clear what _custom RTTI information_ should be. There's no such thing IIRC.

Comment: "I would need to know the name of the type and the name of the method."

Comment: Assuming I have this: `template <typename jsType, AIErr(*Type::*Method)()>
    static bool ExecuteMethod(JSContext *cx, unsigned argc, JS::Value *vp)
    {
        const char* jst = typeid(jsType).name();
        const char* t = typeid(Type).name();
        const char* m = typeid(Method).name();

        const type_info& jsti = typeid(jsType);
        const type_info& ti = typeid(Type);
        const type_info& mi = typeid(Method);`, the method name won't be retrieved, or I don't know how.

Comment: Additionally, I've got a runtime error sometimes when I have used this code, I can't reproduce anymore, but I'll post that if I get it again.

Answer (score 2):

"*What is this template<> class TypeParseTraits< X >? An override? A specialization?*" - it is partial specialization of template. In this particular case given macro ensures that *TypeParseTraits* template instantiated with 'registered' type will have method *name* that returns const std::string that contains *the name of type, used in code* instead of anything returnad by type_info.name() (which is implementation-defined and often hard to understand).

*My question is, how should I implement (even for debug only) a RTTI info using strings? What are the most effective options, if any?* - the best way for RTTI should be just some virtual method that will return for example a string. This method should be overriden in all derived classes (that could be simplified with *static polymorphism* approach) and return respective info.

*I know that simple char* is not an option as parameter for templates.* - not in general, but...

- it is possible to have static const char* data in struct or class
- is possible to fill this data with the help of template
- it is possible to pass such struct as a template parameter and extract static data
- it is possible to fill such strings manually if the member is *constexpr* (with some penalties though)

Thus you may use types (possibly templates) to pass char*s into other templates.

Example:

```
template<class C>
struct Named { static const char* name; };
template<class C>
const char* Named<C>::name = typeid(C).name(); // fill as you wish

template<class N>
void print() { cout<< N::name <<endl;}
...
print<Named<int>>();
```