# Specialize member function for stl container

Tags: c++, templates, stl, template-specialization

I have a class like this:

```
class Foo
{

    ...
    template<template<typename...> class container>
    void fillContainer(container<int> &out)
    {
        //add some numbers to the container
    }
    ...

}
```

I did it this way to be able to handle different stl Containers. Now I want to create a specialization for std::vector to reserve the Memory (I know the amount of numbers to insert). I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097811/c-syntax-for-explicit-specialization-of-a-template-function-in-a-template-clas) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777236/gcc-error-explicit-specialization-in-non-namespace-scope-desperate-for-help) post, so I did the following:

```
class Foo
{
    //Same Thing as above
}

template<>
void Foo::fillContainer(std::vector<int> &out)
{
    //add some numbers to the container
}
```

Now I get the error: `error: no member function 'fillContainer' declared in 'Foo'`. I guess the Problem is `template<template<typename...> class container>`.

Is there a possibility to specialize this function for `std::vector`?

Comment: Why not just overload it for `vector<int>`?

Comment: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no reason to try and specialize it, just add an overload:

```
class Foo
{
    ...
    template<template<typename...> class container>
    void fillContainer(container<int>& out)
    {
        //add some numbers to the container
    }

    void fillContainer(std::vector<int>& out)
    {
        //add some numbers to the container
    }

    ...
};
```

(There are a few, obscure cases where it makes a difference, such as if someone wants to take the address of the function template version, but nothing that requires it to be specialized rather than the much simpler approach of overloading.)