# Linker errors for namespace being included multiple times

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, linker, defined

I'm trying to fix an "explicit specialization in non-namespace scope" error using the method described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3052604/561309). So I managed to move the templated functions into a separate namespace, and I'm calling these functions from my class (see the code below).

The code now compiles, however I'm getting linker errors " already defined in main.obj" for all the functions in the namespace. I thought that adding `#ifndef STYLE_H` at the top would prevent the namespace from being included multiple times or am I missing something? How can I fix this error?

Below is my code (simplified):

```
#ifndef STYLE_H
#define STYLE_H

namespace hanzi {

namespace styleUtil {

    template <class T> 
    T get(const QString& name, T defaultValue = T(), const Style* style = NULL, const Style* baseStyle = NULL) {    
        // ...
    }

    template <> 
    QColor get<QColor>(const QString& name, QColor defaultValue, const Style* style, const Style* baseStyle) {  
        // ...
    }

    template <> 
    ImagingEffect get<ImagingEffect>(const QString& name, ImagingEffect defaultValue, const Style* style, const Style* baseStyle) { 
        // ...
    }

}

class Style : public QObject {

    Q_OBJECT

public:

    explicit Style(const QString& filePath);

    template <class T> 
    T get(const QString& name, T defaultValue = T()) const {
        return styleUtil::get<T>(name, defaultValue, this, baseStyle_);
    };

};

}

#endif // STYLE_H
```

Comment: The word "namespace" in the error doesn't mean what you think. Instead, you should read it as "You cannot add specialisations to a class definition".

Comment: @Laurent Are you missing a forward declaration of Style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the original error,

> I'm trying to fix an "explicit specialization in non-namespace scope" error

What that error means is that you cannot define member function template specializations inside a class definition. I.e. the following would be illegal:

```
struct Bar
{
    template <typename T> void boo() { }
    // template <> void boo<char>() { boo<int>(); }  // Error! Cannot specialize here
};
```

However, this is solved by simply placing the specialisation *outside* the class definition:

```
template <> void Bar::boo<char>() { boo<int>(); }  // Good.
```

(The latter position of the specialization is "at namespace scope", for example at global scope, which is what the error message wanted to tell you to do.)

Answer (score 2):

A full specialization of a function template is no longer a template: it is a function.

As such, when you define it in a header, you need to add the keyword `inline`.

`inline` changes the behavior of C++'s "One Definition Rule" (ODR). Essentially, with `inline` the function must be defined in every translation unit where it’s used, and those definitions must be effectively equal. Both accomplished by placing the definition in a header file.

`inline` also serves as a hint about optimization, but that second meaning is not guaranteed.

Also note, so this answer does not mislead you, there is no such thing as a partial specialization of a function template.