# Compilation error C2976 with boost::asio by using template with std::enable_if

Tags: c++, templates, boost, enable-if, asio

I've written a c++ class that work's fine by using it in a test program. By using it in my project, there is a compilation error C2976. So i reduced the code to show the problem:

source.h

```
#include <type_traits>
//#include <boost/asio.hpp>

namespace myNS {

class Dummy {
public:
   Dummy() {}
   ~Dummy() {}

   template<class T> struct _isValidType : std::false_type {};
   template<> struct _isValidType<bool> : std::true_type {};
   template<> struct _isValidType<int> : std::true_type {};
   template<class T> struct isValidType : _isValidType<std::remove_cv_t<T>>::type {};

   template<typename OUT, typename std::enable_if<isValidType<OUT>::value>::type* dummy = nullptr>
   OUT doSomething() {  OUT out{}; return out; }
};

} /* namespace myNS */
```

source.cpp

```
#include "source.h"

int main() {
   myNS::Dummy d;
   bool b = d.doSomething<bool>();
}
```

There is no compilation error when boost::asio is not included. By including boost::asio the compiler runs in error on the last template definition:

```
source.h(14): error C2976: "Dummy::isValidType": Nicht genügend Vorlage-Argumente.
source.h(12): note: Siehe Deklaration von "Dummy::isValidType"
source.h(14): error C2955: "Dummy::isValidType" : Für die Verwendung von Klasse Vorlage ist eine Vorlage-Argumentliste erforderlich
source.h(12): note: Siehe Deklaration von "Dummy::isValidType"
source.h(15): error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.
```

Does anyone know this problem? Is it the fault of boost::asio, of MSVC, or is it my fault? In this example boost::asio is not necessary to be included, but in my project i have to include it.
I'm working with MS Visual Studio Community 2017 V 15.5.5 and use the boost library v1.66.0.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you calling `doSomething()`?

Comment: You can't explicit specialize a template in class scope. Move those explicit specialization out to the namespace scope.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explicit specialization in non-namespace scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052579/explicit-specialization-in-non-namespace-scope)

Comment: I have the same problem by using a namespace

Comment: @werner Compiles fine: https://wandbox.org/permlink/kq40FRS2rOmo98Sv

Comment: @ liliscent: yes, you'r right. In wandbox.org it compiles fine without boost::asio and with boost::asio. In MSVC it doesn't.

Comment: @werner Maybe you need to re-tag your question, since it's MSVC specific, it compiles fine both for clang and gcc.

Answer (score 1):

This caused by some bad `#define OUT ...` (see <kbd>[Live Repro](https://godbolt.org/g/63nSqo)</kbd>).

Rename your `OUT` type parameter to something else and move the explicit specializations outside the class.

```
class Dummy {
public:
    // ...
    template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<isValidType<T>::value>::type* dummy = nullptr>
    T doSomething() {  T out{}; return out; }
}:

template<> struct Dummy::_isValidType<bool> : std::true_type {};
template<> struct Dummy::_isValidType<int> : std::true_type {};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it's still the same problem. It doesn't matter if it is outside the class or outside the namespace.

Comment: @werner Rename `OUT` to `T` or something

Comment: THANKS! The problem is OUT. If i change to T or another character it works fine. OUT and IN doesn't work. What's the reason?

Comment: @werner I suppose it comes from some Windows.h header